# Convert System.Windows.Forms.Shortcut into KeyData / KeyCode

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

Is there an easy way to get the corresponding keydata (keycode combination) for some value in that enum?

I cannot find one, and creating a switch statement for all those is a bit overkill...

The integer values of the enum elements are not keycodes, but some 'unknown' big numbers, so simply casting to int won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lower 4 bytes are the key and the upper 4 bytes are a mask for Shift, Ctrl and Alt-Key, So you can get the KeyCode with something like this:

```
Shortcut shortcut = Shortcut.ShiftDel;
Debug.Print((((int)shortcut) & 0xFFFF).ToString());
```

Will output `46` which is the code for del key.

Answer (score 3):

System.Windows.Forms.Shortcut and System.Windows.Forms.Keys can be cast directly (their integer values match).

```
Keys keys = (Keys) Shortcut.CtrlL;
```

Comment: @Denis: I appreciate the effort of adding an example to my answer, but the "probably" twice does not suit me, sorry. You could instead provide your own answer, or add a comment.